# POST one data value in 2 models Json, mongoDB, MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, postman

I created a code that has 2 functions;

```
module.exports.registerAccount = (reqBody) => {

let newAccount = new User({
    firstName : reqBody.firstName,
    lastName : reqBody.lastName,
    email : reqBody.email,
    mobileNum : reqBody.mobileNum,
    password : bcrypt.hashSync(reqBody.password, 10)
})

return await newAccount.save().then((account, error) =>{
    if(error){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
})

let newCustomer = new Order ({
    FirstName : reqBody.firstName,
    LastName : reqBody.lastName,
    MobileNum : reqBody.mobileNum
})

return await newCustomer.save().then((customer, error) =>{
    if(error){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
})
}
```

The newAccount is for the user model and the newCustomer is for the order model,
I tried the codes and there's no error but the newCustomer is not saving in its model. I also tried to swap the position of the two model and the result is also swap. is there a way to make both of it work in one go? can I have some tips?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution;

```
return newAccount.save() && newCustomer.save().then((account, error) =>{
    if(error){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
})
```

since that only one return statement is working I used && in between newAccount and newCustomer.

Comment: `return !!error` instead